# Can't import table or stored procedure using npgsql and entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-6, npgsql

as soon as i import my table to my created model i get the following errors: warning 6005: The data type 'inet' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'm_plc_id' in the table 'test_morteza.zd.t_turbine_details' was excluded. warning 6031: The column 'm_plc_id' on the table/view 'test_morteza.zd.t_turbine_details' was excluded, and is a key column. The table/view has been excluded. Please fix the entity in the schema file, and uncomment

Comment: Please provide more details regarding what you're doing, what you expect and what problems you're having. See here for some hints to get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: as soon as i import my table to my created model i get the following errors:                                                                                                          
warning 6005: The data type 'inet' is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'm_plc_id' in the table 'test_morteza.zd.t_turbine_details' was excluded.
warning 6031: The column 'm_plc_id' on the table/view 'test_morteza.zd.t_turbine_details' was excluded, and is a key column.  The table/view has been excluded.  Please fix the entity in the schema file, and uncomment.